# MariaDB innodb_ft_max_token_size Issue

Tags: mariadb, mariadb-10.6

I'm using MariaDB 10.6.8 and I can't seem to get the innodb_ft_max_token_size to go any higher than 84. The documentation states the range is between 10 and 252 ([innodb_ft_max_token_size](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/innodb-system-variables/#innodb_ft_max_token_size)).  Do I need a newer version of MariaDB?

Comment: 252 = 84*3.  Maybe there is a 3-bytes-per-character constraint of some kind going on here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation was (I just fixed it) incorrect. @NovaDenizen was right in the 3 factor which is part of the current code base [HA_FT_MAXCHARLEN](https://github.com/MariaDB/server/commit/b66c016f130934a8ee5a82b572bc46c93ad1f3e7#diff-08ddffbf214b6a119a41e1526241acba21385ec46301e013da6970025aa622f6R30) which defines the maximum value of [innodb_ft_max_token_size](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/innodb-system-variables/#innodb_ft_max_token_size).

Comment: It was pointed out that I didn't answer the "Do I need a newer version of MariaDB?" question, and on the basis of this question, the answer is no. If you do need a larger innodb_ft_max_token_size value than 84, do request it as a [task](https://jira.mariadb.org). It wasn't clear to me if this was going to be an easy change or not in the codebase.